# Issue in installing my App from AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios

When i install my app form AppStore(latest version), it gets downloaded and once it gets downloaded, it shows "UPDATE" instead of "OPEN". Only on clicking UPDATE and downloading it again, it gets opened. What could be the issue?

Comment: show application link

Comment: @Rajneesh071: Got my application link?

Answer (score 1):

If there's any problem at all, I'm sure it is not related to your app, as it cannot affect what happens outside of it.